# How Do I Redirect A User To A Product Page Instead Of Seeing Standard Content Restriction Message?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website with WooCommerce and WooCommerce Memberships installed.

A variety of pages are Content Restricted based on the default WooCommerce Membership setting "Hide Content Only" which can be viewed under WooCommerce --> Settings --> Memberships.

If a user tries to view a page which requires a product purchase, they will see a standard "You need to purchase XYZ in order to access this page".

What I would like to do is to completely bypass this, and simply have the site send the user to the correct product they would need to purchase in order to access the restricted material.

I can crudely assume the PHP redirect logic might look like this:

```
If viewer tries to access restricted content {
   is user logged in?
    - no —> redirect to product page 
    - yes —> has user purchased product?
        - yes —> access
        - no —> redirect to product page
}
```

...however I am still learning all of the components inside WooCommerce along with the elements you would need to call in a function like this. I'd think that the data points for model might include:

```
user_id, membership_plan_id, product_id, product_page_id, page_category
```

I believe the files inside WC Memberships that control how the Content Restriction systems works included under /includes and /includes/functions.

Appreciate any help here, thanks!

Here's a [link to more info](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-settings/) on how WC Membership's Content Restriction works.

Comment: Have you tried any filters at all? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-hook-reference/#wc_memberships_user_membership_cancelled_notice

Comment: I have not, thanks for the suggestion!